# Styling navigationController per viewController

Tags: swift, ios

The design of my application consists of multiple viewControllers which all have different styling applied to them. The following code is used in **every** viewController to style the viewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.title = "PROFILE"

        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = self.view.tintColor

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default

        tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
        tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = .white
        tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .black
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
```

Some properties change per VC, for example the backgroundColor of the VC. This code is copy pasted in every VC I make with small changes, which causes a lot of duplicate code etc. Is there a design pattern which allows me to create the styling of every VC more conveniently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extension **UIViewController**   create  a navigation bar Method call anywhere  from ViewController  in your project.navigation bar will appear   and  add more parameter  color or other relevant change you want to achieved .

for example

```
    import UIKit

    extension UIViewController {

        func setupNavigationBar(title: String) {
            // back button without title
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

            //back button color
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

            //set titile
             self.navigationItem.title =  title

            //set text color & font size
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.init(red: 251/255, green: 251/255, blue: 251/255, alpha: 1) , NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)]

            //set background color without gradian effect
            //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 134/255, green: 145/255, blue: 152/255, alpha: 1)

            //show right button 
            let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menu))

            //right Bar Button Item tint color 
            //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 219/255, green: 219/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1)

            //show the Menu button item
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

            //show bar button item tint color 
            //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 219/255, green: 219/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1)

        }

        func menu(){ 
            print("showSlideOutMane fire ")
        }

    }
```